# Android SoundPool + AudioEffects

Tags: android, soundpool, audioeffect

I am currently using the **SoundPool** for gapless looping over short sample clips - works good so far.

Now I would like to **add effects** to one or both channels (BassBoost or PresetReverb).

Can I do this with the SoundPool?
Do I have to use Audiotrack instead? (MediaPlayer would be too heavy).
Can the Audiotrack loop gapless?

Thanks, paper.

Comment: SoundPools use sessionId 0 as far as I know.